# Код ошибки 400 при создании бота

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, telegram-bot, бот, обработка-ошибок

Прохожу урок, написано также, как и в уроке, но при этом выдает ошибку:

```
function sendMessage() { 
  let chat_id = 300973801; 
  let text = "hello!"; 
  let url = "api.telegram.org/…" + chat_id + " & text = " + text; 
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
  Logger.log(response); 
}
```

Comment: Вам необходимо скопировать код и вставить текстом, чтоб другие смогли попробовать его воспроизвести и написать вам ответ, удобный для вас на базе вашего кода

Comment: function sendMessage() {
  let chat_id = 300973801;
  let text = "hello!";
  let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot2048670328:AAF-3dAcKFIHX_GlmfLMT_AKFDq0Jeu6fPA/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + " & text = " + text;
 let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 Logger.log(response); 
}

Comment: error 400 означает, что запрос неправильно сформирован, возможно вам надо добавить какие-то токены или еще что-то?

Comment: Язык `JavaScript`? Добавьте тег языка